# How can I see commit pushed in different branches together?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I want to list down last commits which were made in different branches together. ie. I want to see the branch name, even if I've forgotten in some cases.

**Scenario =>** Let's take - I was working in 3 different branches in a single day & I wanted to see what last commits I have made in all those 3 branches together ie. - Not by mentioning any branch name.

I can get all commits pushed in a particular branch with this command -

```
git log mybranchName
```

**Is there any provision which can give me result like -**

Branch `login` => `commit: Added form design.`

Branch `register` => `commit: Registration module completed.`

Branch `master` => `commit: Release v1.0.0`

**Note -** Not just 3 branches, It should be a flag to get how many of the last branches I wanted to list down. The only purpose is to list down the branches in which I am working on without jotting down it.

Also happy if any flag can help me to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

Comment: `git log --all --since=yesterday`?

Comment: @jthill - It's not doing anything for me.

Comment: @AnujRaghuvanshi, can you please review your pending change to my answer? Yes, `log` was missing, thanks, but I have sorted the options for a good reason, explained in the link.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/5825294) question.

One good command to see all branches at the same time in a nice way is the following:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

To remember it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/5825294).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using simple graphical interface like [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk/1.6.1) or [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/) you can pass `--all` option and it will list all branches with commits: